# possibility one DataTable with multiple lists

Tags: list, jsf, if-statement, datatable

I got 2 datatables with exact the same column. The only difference is that one datatable got filtered data. Now I'm showing only one datatable using an IF statement. Isn't there a shorter way where I could use like 1 datatable where I could put some sort of IF statement if so it knows which list to use?

Does anyone has an idea how I can put these datatables together?

This is a part of my code so you'll get a better idea of what I mean:

(BTW: the only difference between the 2 datatables is the if-statement)

```
<c:if test="#{destinationController.selectedCountry != null and destinationController.selectedDestination == null}">
     <h:dataTable value="#{destinationController.listTripsByCountry}" var="trip" rendered="#{destinationController.selectedCountry != null}">

         <h:column>
             <f:facet name="header">#{bundle.startdate}</f:facet>
                 <h:outputText value="#{trip.beginUur}">
                     <f:convertDateTime pattern="h:mm" />
                 </h:outputText>
                 <h:outputText value="#{trip.beginDatum}">
                     <f:convertDateTime pattern=" d MMM yyyy" />
                 </h:outputText>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">#{bundle.enddate}</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{trip.eindUur}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="h:mm" />
                </h:outputText>
                <h:outputText value="#{trip.eindDatum}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern=" d MMM yyyy" />
                </h:outputText>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</c:if>


<c:if test="#{destinationController.selectedCountry != null and destinationController.selectedDestination != null}">
    <h:dataTable value="#{destinationController.listTripsByDestination}" var="trip" rendered="#{destinationController.selectedCountry != null}"
                                 >

         <h:column>
             <f:facet name="header">#{bundle.startdate}</f:facet>
                 <h:outputText value="#{trip.beginUur}">
                     <f:convertDateTime pattern="h:mm" />
                 </h:outputText>
                 <h:outputText value="#{trip.beginDatum}">
                     <f:convertDateTime pattern=" d MMM yyyy" />
                 </h:outputText>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">#{bundle.enddate}</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{trip.eindUur}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="h:mm" />
                </h:outputText>
                <h:outputText value="#{trip.eindDatum}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern=" d MMM yyyy" />
                </h:outputText>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Well, there is just an idea but you will have to do some extra work on the backing bean. Why don't you take your decision on the backing bean and set the destinationController.listTripsByDestination or destinationController.listTripsByCountry in one list based on the decision. And then simply populate that on the page. This way, you will not have to write the same code twice :) Hope this will help.

Comment: @Mr.777 That's actually a very good idea and not so hard. Thanks!